# How do I deploy a point release such as 14.04.2 from MAAS?

Tags: maas

I am using MAAS and using a NIC that requires a later kernel than is provided by 14.04.0 trusty release.  The point release 14.04.2 works.

How do I deploy a point release for supported hardware directly from MAAS, rather than deploying the 14.04.0 release and then upgrading, as this will not work with the NIC being used.

Answer (score 1):

You edit a node and select the architecture to be

- `amd64/hwe-u` for utopic and
- `amd-64/hwe-v` for vivid kernels.

To get all kernel releases including development ones update the boot images sync url, in the settings page to be:
http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/daily/
and then re-import the boot images.